# BCNF and 3NF Database Questions with Functional Dependencies

Tags: database, rdbms, 3nf, bcnf

Hello I have been working on these problems for a couple of days and was hoping to receive some feedback on the answers I have obtained through trying to figure out these problems.

Question: Consider relation R(ABCDE) with FDs AB --> C, 
AC --> B, BC --> A, D --> E.

1.) If the set of FDs over R is not a minimal basis, write down a minimal basis for the set of FDs over R.

```
Answer: The set of FDs over R is already a minimal basis
{AC --> B, BC --> A, AB --> C, D --> E}
```

2.) If the relation is not in 3NF, decompose it into a schema that is in 3NF.

```
Answer: The relation R is not in 3NF thus we need to decompose into 3NF
Decomposed schemas:
R{D,E}
R{B,C,D}
R{A,B,C}
```

3.) If the relation is not in BCNF, decompose it into a schema that is in BCNF.

```
 Answer: Relation R is in BCNF, there are no violations for BCNF thus 
         relation R is in BCNF form.
```

If I could have some feedback on if my answers are completely incorrect or if I am close and messed up on something small I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that R is *not* in 3NF, but it *is* in BCNF. That's *literally* nonsense. To show that a relation is not in 3NF, show the transitive dependency. To show that a relation is in BCNF, show that every arrow is an arrow out of a candidate key.

Comment: Yes I am sorry you are right, I wasn't paying attention to that definition. I instead was looking for a BCNF decomposition example and I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMnWvJk0guI and thought I would need to do it this way and going through I couldn't find a violation. I will keep trying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be in my class...

Anyway first off, there is something wrong with two and three. If a relation is in bcnf, by definition it has to be in 3nf. But the 3nf decomposition looks okay. I have no idea about part a.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad about the definition, I am trying to figure out this BCNF violation and decomposition thing right now. Have any tips on where to go from the relation to start off? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The set of FDs over R is not a minimal basis
given the FD's we can find key of R is ABD
then we find minimal basis  which is -
`{AB --> C, D --> E}`

According to FD's this relation in BCNF.
Because `{AB}+= A,B,C;` 
        `{D}+=D,E;` satisfying the BCNF condition.
So don't need to decompose.